# npm can't install any packages and doesn't show any errors

Tags: node.js, git, visual-studio-2015, npm, npm-install

OS: Windows 10

Git: 2.10.1

Node: 4.6.0

NPM: 2.15.9

I created empty test folder and I'm trying to install bower and other packages inside via windows console and seeing only loader for a long time, without any errors, but nothing is installed.

Just notice, earlier I tried to install packages in visual studio 2015 with using bower and npm, and I also didn't have any errors. I see this:

> PATH=.\node_modules.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External\git
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External\Bower.cmd" install --force-latest
>
> bower bootstrap#3.3.5       not-cached https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.3.5
>
> bower bootstrap#3.3.5          resolve https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.3.5

And everything stopped at this step. But in task manager I had some Node.js server instances that are working but nothing is installed.

Then I decided to create simple project not in visual studio. When I installed Git, I chose "Use Git from the Windows Command Prompt". And I changed global git config:

> git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://

But nothing helped me. How can I resolve that?